# Transform tag and inner data into key value pairs

Tags: javascript, regex

#### Pattern

`<DISTURBED>Open your eyes</DISTURBED><Field Two>See through the disguise</Field Two>`

The [regular expression I'm using](https://www.regex101.com/r/OvKFjS/1) only gives me the last result:

`(<([\w\s?[^>]*)>([\w\s?]*)<\/[\w\s?[^>]*>)*`

#### Output

I need to extract all data into key value pairs.  In this case:

`{"DISTURBED": "Open your eyes", "Field Two": "See through the disguise" }`

Another possible output could be:

```
{"DISTURBED": "Open your eyes", "Field Two": "See through the disguise", "KeyNameX": "Value output Y" }
```

#### General Rules

- Theoretically supports any # of `<tag name>inner content</tag name>` values. Realistically, there is no need to support > 50 tags following such pattern:

  `<tag>value</tag><tag2>value</tag2><tag3>...<tag50>content</tag50>`
- Nesting is illegal:

  `<tag><innertag>some value</innertag></tag>` //NO
- This is not HTML. You will not see attribute values.
- Character support is limited to words and spaces.  No "!@#$%^&*()_=" etc.

Comment: "(but not > 50) and no nesting": what does it mean? Could you show counter-examples?

Comment: I'm somewhat disappointed that someone with that much rep hasn't read [How do I format my code blocks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)...

Comment: Is there a space between `"Field" and `"two"`?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Are spaces required, or can `"Field_two"` be substituted for `"Field two"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an element, use `.innerHTML`, `.tagName`, `.textContent`, `.replace()` to include, replace `_` character at `.tagName` to preserve space character.

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<DISTURBED>Open your eyes</DISTURBED><Field Two>See through the disguise</Field Two>"
                .replace(/\s+(?=\w+>)/g, "_");

var obj = {};
var nodes = div.childNodes; 
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  obj[nodes[i].tagName.replace(/_/g, " ")] = nodes[i].textContent;
};

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
const re = /<([\w\s]+)>(.+?)<\/\1>/g
```

JavaScript's regex flavour supports back-references.

Then you can loop while you have a match:

```
const string = "<DISTURBED>Open your eyes</DISTURBED>...";
const tags = {};
for (let match; match = re.exec(string);) {
    tags[match[1]] = match[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into lots of problems and decided to toss the idea of a regex out.  I wrote [this](http://codepen.io/smacky311/pen/BQxEvV?editors=0011) thing instead which I called a tokenizer:

```js
   var workingObject = {
  content: "<DISTURBED>Open your eyes</DISTURBED><Field Two>See through the disguise</Field Two><Field Two three>See through the disguise</Field Two three><hi>asdf</hi>",
  result: {}
}

function tokenizer(input){    
  var token;
  var index = 0;
  input.content = input.content.trim();
    
  do{
    token = input.content.substring(0,1);
    input.content = input.content.substring(1, input.content.length);
    
    var tagName = extract(input, '>');
    var tagContent = extract(input, '<');
    var discard = extract(input, '>');
    
    //input.result['"' + tagName + '"'] = {tagContent, index};//optionally add index 
    input.result['"' + tagName + '"'] = tagContent;    
    index++;
  }while(token = '<' && input.content != "");
  
  console.log('final result: ', input.result);
}

function extract(input, delimiter){
  var result = [];
  var token;  
  
  do{
    result.push(token);        
    token =  input.content.substring(0,1);
    input.content =  input.content.substring(1, input.content.length);
  }while(token != delimiter && input.content != "");
  
  result = result.join("");
  return result;
}

tokenizer(workingObject);
```

It's a little more flexible because I don't have to worry about the character details like I would with a regex.  The input tends to process for the most part even if it comes in using unexpected formats.